# Test Weekday then Add Number to Date in R

Tags: r

I've got a column with dates (df$Date) and I would like to create a new column (df$NewColumn) that adds a variable number of days depending on the day of the week (using Lubridate's wday) that is in df$Date, e.g.:

```
df$NewColumn <- ifelse(wday(df$Date) == 6, df$Date + 3,
                       ifelse(wday(df$Date) == 7, df$Date + 3,
                              df$Date + 2))
```

It is seemingly working, only problem is my date format is in a 16XXX format and I can't seem to convert it back to a proper-looking date. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give a sample of one of your dates ? I am not sure what the 16XXXX format is.

Comment: For an explanation of why `ifelse` is changing the format, see the Warning section in `?ifelse`.

Comment: One example is the formula is taking "2015-10-05" and (I believe) adding 2 to equal 16716.

Comment: There was an error in the Lotus123 Date code that was copied by Microsoft that created dates off by two with an offset from 1899-12-31. So maybe this number is from Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to use the `class()` function:

```
R> testdate <- 16716
R> class(testdate) <- "Date"
R> testdate
[1] "2015-10-08"
```

Comment: Fix worked! Any idea why it was "breaking" (i.e. changing formats)? Would love to understand for my own learning.

Comment: not sure, this is something I have just learned to live with since I started using R. Will be curious to read if anyone else posts a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: @stevenjoe ; `ifelse` does weird things with the classes of the objects returned. It's fairly common that you need to restore the class of objects with attributes such as Dates.

Comment: Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, `ifelse` changes formats. If you can avoid using it, then the format should stay the same. The following code creates the output you're looking for:

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2011/01/01",
                                "2011/01/02")))

df$NewColumn <- df$Date + 2 + as.numeric(wday(df$Date)>=6)
```